# Which is more powerful and useful for programming Qt in c++ or qml?

Tags: qt, qt4

If i am creating a GUI based application for multiple  platform which would be best to use?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this question? The advice of a programmer based on its taste on how to write an application he knows almost nothing about? :-) I'n not even sure this question belongs here, but at least you might consider adding some details about you're application...

Comment: i want to create skype like application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very probably, you'll have to code the application specific part of the code in C++ anyway, and the data processing is faster in C++ than in Javascript.